# How to safely convert/copy volatile variable?

Tags: c, volatile

```
volatile char* sevensegment_char_value;

void ss_load_char(volatile char *digits) {
    ...
    int l=strlen(digits);
    ...
 }

 ss_load_char(sevensegment_char_value);
```

In the above example I've got warning from avr-gcc compiler

```
Warning 6   passing argument 1 of 'strlen' discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
```

So I have to somehow copy the value from volatile to non-volatile var? What is the safe workaround?

Comment: Why is `sevensegment_char_value` declared as `volatile` in the first place ? Is it mapped to I/O registers perhaps, or is it memory that is being updated by another thread or interrupt routine ?

Comment: Casting volatile to non volatile is i think Undefined behavior

Comment: @PaulR: both main program and ISR are actively working with this var. ISR is reading the value, main program is modifying it. `ss_load_char(...)` is being called from ISR.

Comment: OK - how do you know the data is valid at interrupt time ? Does the main program disable interrupts while modifying the data ? (The reason I'm asking is that I want to determine whether `volatile` really is needed here.)

Comment: @PaulR: I know it's valid because it's volatile and reading from it will not bring me cached data. If not considering raise conditions, then it is fine. I just don't want to modify this var and in ISR find the old value. There is no syncing mechanism as you described.

Comment: I think you may be missing my point: how do you know that the main routine wasn't part way through updating the data when the interrupt happened ? Do you disable interrupts while updating the data ?

Comment: @PaulR: it sounds like you are talking about raise condition. I don't disable interrupt because other routines depending on that interrupt. The worst thing that could happen, (assuming 16 bit address on 8 bit MCU) if MSB of pointer address will be new and LSB will be old. Correct? if yes, then this is another point of consideration.

Comment: How is the main program changing the variable? Is it overwriting the contents of the one buffer that `sevensegment_char_value` refers to, or is it changing which of several buffers `sevensegment_char_value` refers to?

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: the last one - it will point to new buffer. Buffers are always newly created.

Comment: It sounds like the pointer should be volatile, if anything, rather than the data ? Anyway, your main routine only needs to disable interrupts very briefly, just while it updates the pointer.

Comment: Doesn't `volatile char*` make pointer volatile?

Comment: No, for that you need `char * volatile sevensegment_char_value`.

Comment: ok, so after making pointer volatile and even disabling interrupts, I still need the volatileness of that variable to avoid caching the pointer value, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such thing like a "built in" Workaround in C. Volatile tells the compiler, that the contents of a variable (or in your case the memory the variable is pointing at) can change without the compiler noticing it and forces the compiler to read the data direct from the data bus rather than using a possibly existing copy in the registers. 
Therefore the volatile keyword is used to avoid odd behaviour induced through compiler optimizations. (I can explain this further if you like)

In your case, you have a character buffer declared as volatile. If your program changes the contents of this buffer in a different context like an ISR for example, you have to implement sort of a synchronisation mechanism (like disabling the particular interrupt or so) to avoid inconsistency of data. After aquiring the "lock" (disabling the interrupt) you can copy the data byte by byte to a local (non-volatile) buffer and work on this buffer for the rest of the routine.

If the buffer will not change "outside" of the context of your read accesses I suggest to omit the volatile keyword as there is no use for it.

To judge the correct solution, a little bit more information about your exact use case would be needed.

Comment: Reading the comment discussion in the original post I have to add something: It sounds like the code shown is used to receive data interrupt driven and then process it in the main loop. I would highly recommend to implement a receive queue that is read by the main loop instead of a "shared buffer". (I add this here as I'm not allowed to write comments (yet)). Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

Standard library routines aren't designed to work on `volatile` objects.  The simplest solution is to read the volatile memory into normal memory before operating on it:

```
void ss_load_char(volatile char *digits) {
  char buf[BUFSIZE];
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; ++i) {
    buf[i] = digits[i];
  }
  int l=strlen(buf);
  ...
}
```

Here `BUFSIZE` is the size of the area of volatile memory.

Depending on how the volatile memory is configured, there may be routines you are supposed to call to copy out the contents, rather than just using a loop.  Note that `memcpy` won't work as it is not designed to work with `volatile` memory.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler warning only means that strlen() will not treat your pointer as volatile, i.e. it will maybe cache the pointer in a register when computing the length of your string.  I guess, that's ok with you.

In general, `volatile` means that the compiler will not cache the variable.  Look at this example:

```
extern int flag;
while (flag) { /* loop*/ }
```

This would loop forever if `flag != 0`, since the compiler assumes that flag is not changed "from the outside", like a different thread.  If you want to wait on the input of some other thread, you must write this:

```
extern volatile int flag;
while (flag) { /* loop*/ }
```

Now, the compiler will really look at flag each time the loop loops.  This may be must more what we intended in this example.

In answer to your question: if you know what you're doing, just cast the volatile away with `int l=strlen((char*)digits)`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Volatile](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/154) on Ian Lance Taylor's blog. Taylor is one of the GCC devs. He points out `volatile` is incorrect in the example you provided. `volatile` is not used for cache consistency.